# Not getting expected content with LWP::UserAgent get() over https

Tags: windows, apache, perl, https, xampp

The below returns

> [HTTP::Response=HASH(0x2ad70dc)] [LWP will support https URLs if the LWP::Protocol::https module is installed. ]

```
#!"\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
print   "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 1 });
my $res = $ua->get("https://news.ycombinator.com/item\?id=25614167");
print "[".$res."]";
print "[".$res->decoded_content."]";
```

I've got "LWP::Protocol::https" installed. "cpanm LWP::Protocol::https" returns "LWP::Protocol::https is up to date. (6.10)"

I've tried writing the above in a host of different ways and pointing at different HTTPS sites; it works on HTTP sites, i have "Net::SSL" installed ("Crypt::SSLeay" is up to date. (0.72)), no firewalls, reinstalled the latest XAMPP server, installed the latest Strawberry Perl in place of the XAMPP one, just run out of ideas, any suggestions welcome.

edit; The shebang line actually points to Strawberry Perl portable, i replaced the XAMPP Perl folder with this so i didn't need to change the shebang line in all my scripts. -but I've also tried this using XAMPPs perl, with same results.

Edit2; since I'm getting warning on this site about answering comments, I'll answer here and clear my replies.

@TLP, $^X was "D:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe" installed new non-portable, changed shebang and $^X is now "C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" but with same results as above. httpd-perl.conf isn't a file in my installation, anyway isn't this upstream of the problem, its running Perl, its Perl that isn't *properly* running its modules..?

@stevieb, perl 5, version 32, subversion 0 (v5.32.0) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int

@Steffen Ullrich, not sure how to use "perl -MLWP::Protocol::https -e ''", but after some research i used eval(); to test if module exists, "LWP::UserAgent" does, but "LWP::Protocol::https" doesn't, even though "cpanm LWP::Protocol::https" in cmd returns "LWP::Protocol::https is up to date. (6.10)".  Same with IO::Socket::SSL and Net::SSLeay.  So this is the problem, not sure now to solve it.

@TLP, "perldoc -l LWP::Protocol::https" returns "C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\LWP\Protocol\https.pm", which exists and is v6.10. "print @INC;" lists;
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/lib".
So it should be finding it in "C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib"..?

Comment: You are not using the Strawberry perl binary, you are using the xmapp perl binary, as shown in your shebang.

Comment: ...so you need to use the `cpan` that came with xampp (or the get `cpanm` to use that `perl`)

Comment: Or conversely, you could have your script use your SP instead of your xampp's Perl.

Comment: @jobeSW The shebang might not be relevant. Try printing the `$^X` executable name to see which one is being used.

Comment: I'm not sure just moving folders is a safe idea, and it feels like that is what is messing things up. Shebangs are normally ignored in Windows anyway, except for switches.

Comment: Shebang is ignored in Windows, like I said.

Comment: What version does `perl -v` say?

Comment: I would try to change some XAMPP setting to direct it to the perl binary you want to use, rather than try to juggle folders around to trick it. httpd-perl.conf is a file mentioned when googling.

Comment: Try to a actually load the file, i.e. `perl -MLWP::Protocol::https -e ''`. It might be that dependencies are missing. And note that you should better use Net::SSLeay + IO::Socket::SSL, not Crypt::SSLeay. See also [DO YOU NEED Crypt::SSLeay?](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::SSLeay#DO-YOU-NEED-Crypt::SSLeay?) in the documentation of Crypt::SSLeay about this.

Comment: `perldoc -l LWP::Protocol::https`. Also might check `@INC`, see if it points to that place. Basically, feels like you have a broken installation.

Comment: Updated post to reply to here.

Comment: There seems to be some interaction with XAMPP. You might add a tag for xampp/apache and get some more experienced people involved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your suggestions, i actually learned a lot here today.

But in the end, the solution was to re-install XAMPP on D: and point the shebang to an msi installed Strawberry Perl on C:.  No other combination would work for me.

I haven't really gotten to the bottom of whats happened, but this solution will let me continue with my project.